# Sum of products of binomial coefficients: proof

Tags: combinatorics

The sum
$$
g_{k}=\sum_{\vphantom{\LARGE A}j,\,i \atop {\vphantom{\LARGE A}i\ +\ j\ =\ k}}
\left(-1\right)^{\,j}{m \choose j}{n \choose i},\qquad
\mbox{for}\quad 0 \leq j \leq m\quad\mbox{and}\quad 0 \leq i \leq n,
$$
is involved in the development of the polynomial $(1+x)^n(1-x)^m$.

It seems to me that the sum
$$\sum_{k}{g_{k} \over k+1} = {2^{n + m} \over (n+m+1){n+m \choose n}}.
$$
Could anybody provide a formal proof or a closed-form development of $g_{k}$ ?,

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have corrected my question

Comment: Write $\sum_k\frac{g_k}{k+1}$ as the integral of a product of two polynomials, then use a substitution. You will recognize an equality involving Gamma and Beta functions.

Comment: The formula is wrong (try $n=1$, $m=2$).

Comment: @FelixMarin Your edit makes the indices in the first summation nearly unreadable. Is it necessary? I suggest to slow down on the sophistication of the LaTeX encoding (Knuth would be horrified by the... things you use) and to concentrate on the readability of the end result.

Answer (score 3):

Writing each $\frac1{k+1}$ as $\int\limits_0^1x^k\mathrm dx$, one gets $S=\int\limits_0^1G(x)\mathrm dx$ with $S=\sum\limits_k\frac{g_k}{k+1}$ and $G(x)=\sum\limits_kg_kx^k$, hence
$$
G(x)=\sum\limits_{i,j}(-1)^j{m\choose j}{n\choose i}x^{i+j}=\sum\limits_{i}{n\choose i}x^{i}\sum\limits_{j}(-1)^j{m\choose j}x^{j}=(1+x)^n(1-x)^m.
$$
Let $x=1-2t$, then $0\leqslant t\leqslant\frac12$, $\mathrm dx=2\mathrm dt$, $1+x=2(1-t)$ and $1-x=2t$, hence $G(x)=2^{n+m}t^m(1-t)^n$ and
$$
S=2^{n+m+1}\int_0^{1/2}t^m(1-t)^n\mathrm dt=2^{n+m+1}\,\mathrm B_{1/2}(m+1,n+1),
$$
where $x\mapsto\mathrm B_x(m+1,n+1)$ is the [incomplete Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) of parameters $(m+1,n+1)$.

Comment: Thank you, as for the post above, it answers perfectly to the question.

Comment: This cannot be, since the two answers give different results (as gracefully acknowledged by @Steven).